# onCreate Options menu is not showing in android 3.1

Tags: android, tablet, android-optionsmenu

i am creating an app only for tablets. I have a preference activity page which i am calling through the OnCreateOptions Menu. The oncreateoptins menu is not working in tablets of android 3 version. Why it is so, i used a Samsung galaxy tab for my testing. When i run the same app in one of my emulator of Samsung galaxy tablet of android 2.2 i am getting the oncreate options menu, can anyone help me in this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think problem is in different handling of options menu. According to [dev guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#options-menu), on Android 3.x `onCreateOptionsMenu()` is called when the activity starts to populate ActionBar, not when user touches the Menu button for the first time

Answer (score 6):

Yes this problem is common , Do one thing give a number less than 11 in the targetSdkVersion in Manifest file or simply remove the tarketSdkVersion. Your problem will be get resolved.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on tablets and I did like raman suggested. Changed the project's build target and the targetSdkVersion (from manifest)  to  10.